# error updating brightway (database_parameters)

Tags: brightway

I got an error when trying to update brightway.

after doing

```
conda update -c cmutel bw2io bw2data
```

I got a warning because there are two possible package resolutions, but updated to bw2data 3.1 and bw2io 0.5.11

now if I try to import brightway I get an import error message

> cannot import name 'database_parameters'

**SOLVED**: I updated conda and then I could update bw2io to version 0.6.RC3 and now I do not have any error message when importing brightway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 3.0 of `bw2data` [changed the way that parameterization works](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/src/710e4d81238bd1b5f300ebbd2259d614f4b50cb3/CHANGES.md?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default); see the [documentation](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/intro.html#parameterized-datasets) and [examples](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/notebooks.html#parameterized-notebooks). If there is still a link to `database_parameters` in the documentation, please file an issue. If you need help migrating database parameters, edit the question.

Comment: I think I was using "incompatible" versions. when I tried to update bw2data again it warned me of an update of conda (v4.4.7 to 4.4.8). Once updated I could update bw2io to 0.6.RC3 .Now I don't have errors when importing brightway2